# Why are the absolute output voltages of the two NOR different in my self-built 555 timer?

Tags: 555, multisim

I tried to build a 555 timer using the [Multisim live online (free version)](https://www.multisim.com/).

I refer to the [Ben Eater's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRlSFm519Bo&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU&index=2) which I believe referred to the 555 timer datasheet.

Here is my circuit and the simulation result.

All the settings are default except the output threshold of the amplifier is set as 0-5V.

The simulation is as I expected but I don't understand why the absolute output voltage of the two NOR is so much different.

1. Why is the lower output voltage of the NOR gate U3 not 0?
2. The higher output voltage of NOR gate U4 is 1V which is below the high threshold (2V) of the logic gate input.  How can that work?

You can open my circuit [in this link](https://www.multisim.com/content/mepV2yCzjmQDMeaV22rmsp/555-timer/).

[image]

Comment: Could it be because of the 100 ohm resistor between emitter and ground? Why it is there, instead of having a base resistor in series to prevent excess current?

Comment: @Justme thank you. I have done as you say but I didn't realize it is right because the output indicators' threshold setting are not consistent with the output of the NOR gates, which confused me. And I will modify my questions.

Comment: For clarification, the original question has been solved: move the 100ohm resistor to the base or just remove it, which should be clear and I did originally do so but the wrongly setting indicator confused me. So the question now is changed to the `why` of the different absolute output voltages which confused me.

Comment: The outputs of the NOR gates might not be strong enough to drive the transistor through the 100 ohm resistor.

Comment: @PStechPaul Removing the 100 ohm resistor, the result is the same

Comment: No, change it to about 5k.

Comment: Changed to 5k. nothing changes except the time intervel.

Comment: Just for kicks, try it on a breadboard not in the simulator. Just to see how close the simulator is to reality.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version of the question the transistor was unable to discharge the capacitor because it had an emitter resistor so it could only pull down to certain voltage before reaching equilibrium.

The components are not ideal.

If you have a heavy load (transistor) on the logic gate output, it will not be able to output logic levels, compared to a case of having a weak load such as input of another logic gate.

Comment: What you said make sense. but why the lower voltage of the NOR without heavy load is not 0? the heavy load NOR out voltage is 1V which is below the high threshold of the logic gate input, how can that work?

Comment: I don't know which logic family chips those are and what logic levels they use. It's a simulator, it can work in any way it wants.

Comment: logic level is 3.3V, input threshold is 0.8V~2V. You may open the circuit on web directly